# Upgrade error on Azure functions

Tags: azure, nuget, updates, azure-functions

We are getting this error when attempting to upgrade the Azure functions project. This is the **log file** we are getting

Restoring packages for

```
C:\Users\User\Source\Repos\xxx_FileService\xxx.AzureFunctions\xxx.AzureFunctions\SE.AzureFunctions.csproj...
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 requires Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1) but version Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3 was resolved.
Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs from 2.1.0-beta4 to 2.1.0-beta1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 xxx.AzureFunctions -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.1.0-beta4) 
 xxx.AzureFunctions -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 2.1.0-beta1)
Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions from 2.1.0-beta4 to 2.1.0-beta1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 xxx.AzureFunctions -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (= 2.1.0-beta4) 
 xxx.AzureFunctions -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (>= 2.1.0-beta1)
Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http from 1.0.0-beta4 to 1.0.0-beta1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 xxx.AzureFunctions -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http (= 1.0.0-beta4) 
 xxx.AzureFunctions -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http (>= 1.0.0-beta1)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'SE.AzureFunctions'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.3832626
========== Finished =========
```

Package References in CS.PROJ

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">   <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>SE.AzureFunctions</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>SE.AzureFunctions</RootNamespace>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="1.0.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.0-alpha6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.0-beta004" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>   </ItemGroup> </Project>
```

Comment: Can you share your package references from SE.AzureFunctions/xxx.AzureFunctions?

Answer (score 3):

I will try to provide you with the background of why you are experiencing the challenge you are, as well as propose a solution for you.

### Background of the issue:

the reason you are experiencing this error is rooted in two places:

1. Microsoft downgraded the following packages (as I am sure the error message you received may have clued you into):

   a.  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs from `2.1.0-beta4` to **`2.1.0-beta1`**

   b.  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http from 1.0.0-beta4 to **`1.0.0-beta1`**
2. In **`.NET Core 2.0.0 Preview 2`** - downgrade warnings have become errors. What this means is that they are configured to treat the warning **`NU1605`** as an error. This is not publicized in their [release notes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/06/28/introducing-asp-net-core-2-0-preview-2/), but if you look into the Property Pages of any project that was templated off the .Net Core 2.0.0 Preview 2 (like I suspect your project is), you would notice that under the `Build` project properties sheet, the warning **`NU1605`** is now being treated as an error (see the Treat warnings as an error section). Let's stick a pin in that for now as we would need to dive into the project's property pages in the proposed solution below.

### Proposed Solution (Note this is a work around!):

Yup, you've guessed it, you need to configure your project to **NOT** treat the **`NU1605`** warning as an error. To do that, follow these steps:

1. Open the property pages of your project,
2. Go to the **`Build`** properties sheet
3. Scroll down to the `Treat Warnings as errors` section, and clear the NU1605 value from the `Specific Warnings` radio box section. (See screen grab below)

[image: clear NU1605 warning as an error]

4. Save and rebuild your project (Nuget might actually attempt to restore the packages automatically when you save your project property pages changes --- if it doesn't do that or if the restore "fails", just rebuild the project and you should be fine)

#### Conclusions

I am sure Microsoft has its reasons for enforcing the downgrade warning **`NU1605`** as an error, so don't take this recommendation of disabling this warning as an error as a blanket endorsement of this tactic; instead treat this recommendation as a work around to a problem that we are all bound to experience when we chose to work with **pre-release** or **beta code**.

My hope is that come the final release candidate, most of these type of dependency issues would have been worked out and such work arounds will not be necessary, but in the mean time, and to keep your alpha/beta/experimental development moving forward, this work around should do.

Hope this helps you and happy coding (ohh yea, **Happy new year!**)